# Conflicting PySpark Storage Level Defaults?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Confused why the cached DFs (specifically the 1st one) are showing different `Storage Levels` here in the Spark UI based off the code snippets

[image]

```py
print(spark.version)
2.4.3

# id 3 => using default storage level for df (memory_and_disk) and unsure why storage level is not serialized since i am using pyspark
df = spark.range(10)
print(type(df))
df.cache().count()
print(df.storageLevel)

# id 15 => using default storage level for rdd (memory_only) and makes sense why it is serialized
rdd = df.rdd
print(type(rdd))
rdd.cache().collect()

# id 19 => manually configuring to (memory_and_disk) which makes the storage level serialized
df2 = spark.range(100)
from pyspark import StorageLevel
print(type(df2))
df2.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK).count()
print(df2.storageLevel)

<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
Disk Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated
```

According the Spark documentation persisted `python` objects are always `serialized` so why is the first `df` showing `deserialized`?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#which-storage-level-to-choose

**Note: In Python, stored objects will always be serialized with the Pickle library, so it does not matter whether you choose a serialized level. The available storage levels in Python include MEMORY_ONLY, MEMORY_ONLY_2, MEMORY_AND_DISK, MEMORY_AND_DISK_2, DISK_ONLY, and DISK_ONLY_2.**

The default storage for `rdd` is `MEMORY_ONLY` and for `df` it is `MEMORY_AND_DISK` so shouldn't the Spark UI be showing `serialized` for all `pyspark` cached dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Found funny thing (possibly it is a bug), Focus on your spark version 2.4.3

In pyspark, when we call [cache()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L605), it will call Java function cache() only

And inside [Scala API](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2956) it will cache with `MEMORY_AND_DISK` and then it is defined in [StorageLevel](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/StorageLevels.java#L33) as `create(true, true, false, true, 1);` the second `true` means deserialized.

In conclusion when you call cache() in pyspark it will always create deserialized object in memory and disk. That is a misbehavior with pyspark as document mentioned it alwasy be serialized.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me why the storage levels are different versus accepting the default in the 1st df which is showing deserialized and then explicitly hard coding to ```MEMORY_AND_DISK``` in the 2nd df which is showing serialized ... perhaps it is recommended to specify ```MEMORY_AND_DISK``` when using spark python

Comment: Yes, you are correct about recommendation. But use `persist` will do the same, it will cache df with `MEMORY_AND_DISK`

Answer (score 0):

I think for pyspark `df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)` stores result in serialized way, you don't require `df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)` for pyspark... This is not same for `df.cache()`..  documentation also mentions this thing only for `df.persist`